# How to create a HTML file Dynamically in raw folder in android

Tags: android

I had an editText the data which i enter there should be stored as html file in raw folder .Can I do that?.And also when i click the button print i want the html page to be get printed via share Intent Which i was unable to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't save anything to the raw folder at runtime. It is packaged up with the apk, and can't be modified.

You'll have to save your html file to either internal storage, or the SDcard.

you can share a url like this:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.google.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

you could try altering it like this for sharing html content directly. I don't know if you'll get any applications that are installed by default that will share it in a meaningful way however.

```
String html = "<html>...</html>";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Comment: Ok Can You Please Describe me that process?

Comment: [Read this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) pay special [attention to this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and [also this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)